# App name in device

Tags: java, android

hi i am a new programmer i have created an app of my own. i am trying to give a name for the app to be displayed in my device, i think it must be given somewhere at manifest file, am i right, if not pls guide me....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes -in the manifest file and strings.xml

AndroidManifest.xml
For the application tag provide the following attribute

`android:label="@string/app_name"`

res\values\strings.xml

`string name="app_name">MyApp`

You can avoid strings.xml instead insert the name in the manifest - it is not a good way to do - it may hurt you later (during localization)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have Eclipse installed, you should do it asap, see http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/eclipse-adt.html for more information.

Then you can open AndroidManifest.xml and go to the Application Tag where you can edit the Label.