# Changing Android App Name

Tags: android, eclipse

My Android Project has the name "MobileApp" but after I install my App, in the App Manager it has the Name "MobileTestApp"

How can I change the App Name?

Comment: possible duplicate of [App name in device](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4977499/app-name-in-device)

Comment: You can change AppName  in Manifest file

Comment: All answer right so upvote for all ....

Comment: You should accept one of them also, either mine or Brontok, since they are most correct, using hardcoded values as suggested by user2754122 is not a good practice and should not be encouraged. Have a nice day and good luck.

Answer (score 2):

In your manifest file under application tag, check for **label**

```
  <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

and then in your **res>values>strings.xml**

update your app name like this

```
 <string name="app_name">MobileApp</string>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Manifest probably:

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

**Label** will be the title shown.

Which is found in the /res/values/strings.xml most likely:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Your App Name</string>
</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest file write this

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="MobileApp">
```

Comment: It is not recommend to use hardcoded Strings like this, if in the future he wants to change the name of his App he might have to do it in several places, thus increasing the probability of inconsistency. Having it in the strings.xml mitigates this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need is explained in the [developer guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html).

In order to change the app name you should modify two files:

in your **Manifest** file the app name is specified with the `android:label` tag:

```
 <application
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Label is pointing to a string into the resource file `string.xml` located in /res/values/strings.xml:

```
<resources>
    <string name="app_name">Your App Name</string>
</resources>
```

It is **recommended** to specify your app name by providing a resource name in your `string.xml`